# Display distances between a point and a line in a plot using R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, geospatial, distance

I want to display distances between a point (colored in Blue) and a line (colored in Black) in a same plot mentioned below. I am using below mentioned statements. I have computed a vector having distance in Meters but dont know how to link distance values with the given plot.

```
 plot(type ="l",longitude, Latitude, xlab="longitude",ylab="latitude")
 points(LONG_P, LAT_P, col = "blue", pch = 20);
 title(main = "Distance between a Line and a Point")
```

Distance values vector

```
[1]  0.000000 49.251046 47.041850  5.004535  5.605959  4.444761  4.444761
[8]  4.444761  4.463635  4.463635  4.463635 47.770314 47.759970 46.596684
[15] 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684
[22] 47.041850  5.605959  4.444761  4.463635  4.463635 47.759970 46.596684
[29] 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684
[36] 46.596684  5.605959  4.463635 47.759970 46.596684 46.596684 46.596684
[43] 46.596684  9.144524  4.463635 46.596684 46.596684  9.144524  9.144524
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You'll have to clarify how the distances should be displayed..

Comment: `apply(cbind(longitude, Latitude), 1, FUN=function(x) segments(LONG_P, LAT_P, x[1], x[2]))` will draw lines from the blue point to all other geographic coordinates. The plot will be incredibly messy. Reconsider plotting the data differently.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked but i cant display value of distances with the lines.

Comment: Try to add the distance data to a matrix and then use it as labels in text: `apply(cbind(longitude, Latitude, Distance), 1, FUN=function(x) {segments(LONG_P, LAT_P, x[1], x[2]); text(x[1],x[2],x[3], pos=3)})`

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I ask how did you find the initial distances from the line?